# Can't install GDK on Catalina

Tags: terminal, macos, homebrew, gitlab

Welcome, while trying to install Gitlab GDK on a MacBook Pro Catalina 16G RAM it goes ok except three dependencies which already exist but the GDK says they are not installed or outdated!

```
bin/gdk install
The following Brewfile's dependencies are missing or outdated:

- dpkg
- git-lfs
- graphicsmagick

To install these dependencies, run the following command:

  (cd /Users/wpplumber/Workspace/Gitlab/dev/gitlab-development-kit && brew bundle)
make[1]: *** [support/makefiles/Makefile.config.mk:208: preflight-checks-run] Error 1
make: *** [support/makefiles/Makefile.timing.mk:4: preflight-checks-timed] Error 2
❌️ ERROR: Failed to install.
-------------------------------------------------------
You can try the following that may be of assistance:

- Run 'gdk doctor'.

- Visit the troubleshooting documentation:
  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/-/blob/main/doc/troubleshooting/index.md.
- Visit https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/-/issues to
  see if there are known issues.

- Run 'gdk reset-data' if appropriate.
- Run 'gdk pristine' which will restore your GDK to a pristine state.
```

After running the cmd: `brew bundle` it shows the following error which seems a bug with tar !

```
==> Fetching dpkg
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/e579248a9a82f75681ed695591446505bb91b864/Formula/d/dpkg.rb
==> Downloading https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.22.0.tar.xz
==> Installing dependencies for dpkg: gnu-tar
==> Installing dpkg dependency: gnu-tar
==> ./configure --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-tar/1.35/share/man --program-pref
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/wpplumber/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gnu-tar/02.make:
      _verify_volume in compare.o
      _process_rawdata in compare.o
      _dump_regular_file in create.o
      _sparse_dump_region in sparse.o
      _main in tar.o
      _read_error_details in libtar.a(paxerror.o)
      ...
  "_libintl_setlocale", referenced from:
      _main in tar.o
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      _main in tar.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [tar] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!

Error: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.


Installing dpkg has failed!
Using exiftool
Using git
Installing git-lfs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after long journey and even the hackathon completed I got it installed.

I recommend the following:
Install: `clang, GCC, Postgres, Redis`

> Use only the brew and asdf package managers.